# Bootstrap navbar-inner not resizing when having lots of links in navbar

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm using Rails 3.2 together with the most actual Bootstrap Gem and the responsive design.
The responsive design itself works fine, except that the navbar doesn't resize or expand automatically when I have more than five link elements in it. This is an issue for mobile clients, where the screen is not large enough to display all links in one row.

My actual workaround was to define this override in my custom.scss file:

```
/* Mobile extras */
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
.navbar-inner {
               min-height: 100px;
              }
}
```

We'll this fixes the problem as long I have exactly five links in the header, but if I have fewer (e.g. user is not logged in) link elements, the navbar has too much height.

I also tried using height:auto and so on, but this didn't help.

Is there any way to get this done by a kind of 'auto' setting?

Comment: Did you read the yellow box titled "Overflowing content" on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar  ?

Comment: Actually not, but I should have before posting....thanks for your hint.